# Combine string and variable to create text label in postscript

Tags: postscript

I have this `Label` definition in postscript:

```js
/Label { % i dx dy (text) Label
% write text at base i plus offset dx, dy
4 3 roll 1 sub coor exch get aload pop moveto
3 1 roll fsize mul exch fsize mul exch rmoveto
show
} bind def
```

It should be used as:

```c
i dx dy (text) Label
```

And I wanted to combine it in a for loop, like this:

```c
1 10 20 {
 /i exch def
 i 0 0 (i) Label
} for
```

To avoid writing:

```c
1 0 0 (1) Label
10 0 0 (10) Label
20 0 0 (20) Label
```

Actually it prints `i` at every position, however I would like to have the index `i` and not `i` as a string there. Any ideas how to combine text and variables? thanks a lot.

Comment: You need to convert the integer into a string, the cvs operator will do that for you. So you need to do "i 256 string cvs" To make your program more efficient consider using the stack instead of defining a key/value pair:
1 10 20 {
dup 0 0 3 -1 roll 256 string cvs Label
} for

Comment: Thanks @KenS, this is working as required! should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

As Ken commented, you need to load the value of the variable and then convert the number into a string. Ken combined these effects into the body of the loop and also eliminated the variable, but another option is define a helper procedure.

```
/to-string {
  256 string cvs
} def
```

And then call it in the code after loading the variable.

```
1 10 20 {
 /i exch def
 i 0 0  i to-string  Label
} for
```

Spacing can help to make the *subexpression* stand out.